# How to use this date of tall array in R ggplot2 Date x-axis order?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, debian

I am thinking how to convert string Date data of tall array format to `Date` and organise the `ggplot` by it in the x-axis by `scale_x_date`.
Pseudocode motivated by Henrik's proposal

1. Change string data format to `as.Date`, maybe something similar to  the following in `ggplot`'s parameter `x = ...`

   ```
   as.Date(time.data, format("%d.%m.%Y")
   ```
2. Apply `scale_x_date` in `ggplot` with `date_breaks("2 day")`

Code with dummy data `data3`

```
library("ggplot2")
# For RStudio
options(device="pdf") # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535927/how-do-i-prevent-rplots-pdf-from-being-generated
filename.pdf <- paste0(getwd(), "/", "Rplots", ".pdf", sep = "")
pdf(file=filename.pdf)
# Dummy data
data3 <- structure(list(Time.data = c("16.7.2017", "15.7.2017", 
                                             "14.7.2017", "13.7.2017", "12.7.2017", "11.7.2017", "9.7.2017", 
                                             "7.7.2017", "6.7.2017", "5.7.2017", "4.7.2017", "3.7.2017", "2.7.2017", 
                                             "1.7.2017", "30.6.2017", "29.6.2017", "28.6.2017", "16.7.2017", 
                                             "15.7.2017", "14.7.2017", "13.7.2017", "12.7.2017", "11.7.2017", 
                                             "9.7.2017", "7.7.2017", "6.7.2017", "5.7.2017", "4.7.2017", "3.7.2017", 
                                             "2.7.2017", "1.7.2017", "30.6.2017", "29.6.2017", "28.6.2017", 
                                             "16.7.2017", "15.7.2017", "14.7.2017", "13.7.2017", "12.7.2017", 
                                             "11.7.2017", "9.7.2017", "7.7.2017", "6.7.2017", "5.7.2017", 
                                             "4.7.2017", "3.7.2017", "2.7.2017", "1.7.2017", "30.6.2017", 
                                             "29.6.2017", "28.6.2017"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                                               3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
                                             ), .Label = c("ave_max", "ave", "lepo"), class = "factor"), 
                        value = c(69, 75, 83, 97, 101, 73, 77, 78, 98, 79, 78, 95, 
                                  70, 81, 78, 71, 72, 58, 59, 59, 58, 54, 56, 60, 60, 62, 58, 
                                  56, 63, 58, 58, 63, 58, 56, 48, 51, 51, 48, 48, 48, 52, 53, 
                                  52, 49, 48, 53, 50, 50, 54, 46, 47)), row.names = c(NA, -51L
                                  ), .Names = c("Time.data", "variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")

#Relevant part of the code based on Henrik's proposal, 
#rejected timestamp approach which output has wrongly shown x-axis label in Fig. 1
p <- ggplot(data3, aes(x = as.Date(Time.data, format = "%d.%m.%Y"), y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1), 
        text = element_text(size=10)) +
  scale_x_discrete("Date") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 days", date_labels = "%d.%m.%Y") 

print(p)
dev.off()
```

Output which I do not understand

```
Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.
```

Fig. 1 Output based on Henrik's proposal

[image]

Expected output: as such but with correct x-label there on the x-axis

OS: Debian 9
R: 3.4.0
RStudio: 1.0.143
Other sources: [Date format for subset of ticks on time axis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24569628/54964), [scale_datetime shifts x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38657343/54964), [Time series plot gets offset by 2 hours if scale_x_datetime is used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37737332/54964)

Comment: "Time.data" seem be dates, so why not use `as.Date` and `scale_x_date`?

Comment: @Henrik Please, see the body for my proposal with a few bugs still there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified *two* different scales for the x axis, a discrete scale and a continuous date scale, presumably in an attempt to rename the label on the x axis. For this, `xlab()` can be used:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data3, aes(x = as.Date(Time.data, format = "%d.%m.%Y"), y = value, fill = variable)) +
  # use new geom_col() instead of  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  # see http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/releases/ggplot2-2.2.0.html#stacking-bars
  geom_col() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1), 
        text = element_text(size=10)) +
  # specify label for x axis
  xlab("Time.date") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 days", date_labels = "%d.%m.%Y")
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the `name` parameter to `scale_x_date()`:

```
ggplot(data3, aes(x = as.Date(Time.data, format = "%d.%m.%Y"), y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1), 
        text = element_text(size=10)) +
  scale_x_date(name = "Time.date", date_breaks = "2 days", date_labels = "%d.%m.%Y")
```

#### Addendum: Saving plots

If the intention is to save just one plot in a file you can add a call to `ggsave()` after the call to `ggplot()`, i.e.,

```
ggplot(...
ggsave("Rplots.pdf")
```

instead of

```
options(device="pdf") # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535927/how-do-i-prevent-rplots-pdf-from-being-generated
filename.pdf <- paste0(getwd(), "/", "Rplots", ".pdf", sep = "")
pdf(file=filename.pdf)
p <- ggplot(...
print(p)
dev.off()
```

According to `help("ggsave")`

> `ggsave()` is a convenient function for saving a plot. It defaults to
>   saving the last plot that you displayed, using the size of the current
>   graphics device. It also guesses the type of graphics device from the
>   extension.

---

Another issue is the creation of the file path. Instead of

```
filename.pdf <- paste0(getwd(), "/", "Rplots", ".pdf", sep = "")
```

it is better to use

```
filename.pdf <- file.path(getwd(), "Rplots.pdf")
```

which constructs the path to a file from components in a platform-independent way.

Comment: Please, see [`ggplot2` v. 2.2.0 News](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/releases/ggplot2-2.2.0.html#stacking-bars): _Note also the new `geom_col()` which is short-hand for `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`_.

Comment: Great appendum!